# Question about source control in Vscode(Mac)

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

Currently, I'm working on a project locally, but I'm not familiar with git, so I posted it here for advice.

[Project Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU0iQ.png)

The current project configuration is like this. I'm currently working on Study/Blockchain/nft-marketplace.

[Vscode Source Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D5XF.png)

The source control in vscode contains the entire Study folder in Changes.

Is there a way to change only the Study/Blockchain/nft-marketplace folder to be included in Changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to open only `nft-marketplace`. Go to `Open folder` and select `nft-marketplace`. If this folder contains a git repo, it will show up in source control. If it does not, initialise a git repo with `git init` in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just put my comment as an answer because, well, it looks like an answer)

Try to open only `nft-marketplace`. Go to `Open folder` and select `nft-marketplace`. If this folder contains a git repo, it will show up in source control. If it does not, initialise a git repo with `git init` in that folder.

Any time you want to open a project in VSCode, open only that project folder**

**unless it is part of a larger, multi-package repo a-la lerna or yarn workspaces... but this is for another story.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I solve this problem